# React native maps issue in iOS app (undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-maps

I am very new to react native. While trying to install **react native map**s (M1 mackbook pro), I am getting the below error (on iOS):
React native version: 0.67 RC 6

Please help me to solve it:

https://rentry.co/n2ixn

This is my POD file:

```html
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'dollseCab' do


  
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )
  
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'dollseCabTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  #use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

and this is AppDelegate.m

```html
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>


static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"APzaSyAOgaVvtCIIkuLcuLJ1thYma3CrpOiq7mI"];

[FIRApp configure];
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
#if RCT_DEV
  [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
#endif
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"dollseCab"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

everything worked fine until I installed google maps

Answer (score 2):

Same here unfortunately. I found it is connected to this [Some tips to working with react-native 0.64 on an Apple M1 Silicon chip](https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/72c5c965fcaefe66d049a8c2cdf34198).

This should help with other packages, but for me I could not get it to run with the google package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's How I solved this issue:

1- Add this in Pod File --> "above config = use_native_modules!"

```
rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

2- At the end of Pod File add this:

```
    post_install do |installer|
                      react_native_post_install(installer)
                      
                      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
                          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                              # Disable arm64 builds for the simulator
                              config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
                          end
                      end
                  end
                end
```

**Note: Also make sure your platform ios is '13.0' or above in Pod File**